# Filling guarded properties in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, password-protection

I want to keep 'password' guarded for security reasons but I also need to fill it when I create a new user.

I have tried many ways and all of them insert the model without the 'password'. This is my most recent attempt.

My Controller:

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
        echo 'fail';
    } else {
        $hash = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        //  input new row
        $user = new User;
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->password = $hash;
        $user->save();
        return $user.$hash;
    }
```

My User Model Code:

```
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

protected $guarded = ['password'];

protected $fillable = ['email'];
```

I've tried making password fillable, I've tried using create().

Let me know if any more information is required. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `guarded` and definitely don't user `guarded` and `fillable` together. Your password is likely saved to the db, however you made it `hidden` so it won't be visible when you return your `$user` cast to string. Just try `return `$user->password` instead

Comment: Why should I not use `guarded`?

Comment: @Helliax [Whitelisting vs. Blacklisting](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/01/whitelisting_vs.html)

Comment: As a good practice. It's more secure when you allow some of the fields, comparing to disallowing. And logically you don't use both whitelist and blacklist.

Comment: Regardless that does not change my issue. I would like password to be guarded. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: @Helliax So what's the issue anyway? I already told you that you won't see the password when you cast `$user` to string. But it's is saved. Mass assignement has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: It worked now. You were right that I wasn't see it. That was my new code and since it gave me the same response as my old code I never actually checked the database. The problem was my old code was trying to do it with Mass Assignment so it never filled.